# Offset in Poisson GLM with log link function where I have values equal to zero

Tags: python, generalized-linear-model, statsmodels, offset

I am trying to build a GLM model (poisson family) using python statsmodels package on train data. The data I have contains categorical values as exogenous variables and numerical values for my target (endegenous variable). I did standardization for numeric values and one-hot-encoding on categorical values (drop the first level). When I fit the data into the model, I got the following exceptions :

```
ValueError: NaN, inf or invalid value detected in endog, 
estimation infeasible.
```

The error comes when creating this model :

```
poisson_model = sm.GLM(endog=y_train, exog=X_train_std, 
   family=sm.families.Poisson(),
   offset = np.log(X_train_std.EXPOSITION))
```

The problem comes from np.log(X_train_std.EXPOSITION) since I can not apply log function on zero values. But I don't know how to correct the error. I need to take into consideration the offset and when changing its link function to identy I get EXPOSITION in the GLM output.

Any help please ? How to deal with offset that takes 0 values with a log link function ?

Comment: What do you mean by "standardization" of the numeric value, subtracting the mean and then dividing by the standard deviation?

Comment: Yes, I meant that.

Comment: Is the response `y_train` always zero in the cases where `X_train_std.EXPOSITION` is zero?

Comment: X_train_std.EXPOSITION is like exposure in the Poisson model. With zero exposure, there should not be any counts. In that case, dropping those observations seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Standardization means that you subtract the mean $\bar y$ and then divide by the standard deviation $s_y$.

$$
z_i = \dfrac{y_i - \bar y}{s_y}
$$

By doing this transformation (unless all $y_i$ are equal, which not an interesting scenario), you create $z_i$ values less than zero, which are out of bounds in Poisson regression. This is what the error message is telling you.

(You also create $z_i$ values that are not even integers! Again, such values are out of bounds in Poisson regression.)

Comment: Clear enough ! Thank you for the explanantion. In this case, can I ignore standardization since I have one only numeric variable which is my offset variable ?

Comment: I do not follow what you mean by an offset variable. @KarimaTouati

Comment: I mean weight variable // exposure..

Comment: Non-integers can make sense for Poisson regression. Some implementations do accept them.